# Better alert window in JavaScript - no need to close, allow to move

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, alert

I need a better function for creating a notification window than alert(), one that allows me to browse the page without closing the alert, and allows me to move the alert window while browsing. Probably something using `<div>`.

Maybe there is some available function that I can use? I can't use libraries, my script is in a Bookmarklet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootbox.js: http://bootboxjs.com/v3.x/ The first example on that page looks like exactly what you need for.

If you can't use library, I suggest you make a div in your webpage and change the visibility/display of the div. Don't forget to set the z-index of the div so the div will be displayed in front of webpage.

Comment: bootboxjs is very nice and it's good to know it, but I can't move the dialog box and also It doesn't allow me to keep browsing the page. Do you know some other function or small libraries?

Comment: "but I can't move the dialog box and also It doesn't allow me to keep browsing the page." It does not allow you to move but it DOES allow you to keep browsing the page if you try the first example in the url I gave.

Comment: Right, sorry. Although it's grayed, I can keep browsing. Thanks for the answer.